# Yammer SSO + API to check User status

Tags: single-sign-on, sharepoint-2013, yammer

I am using yammer embed control with SSO true (**use_sso = true**), it is working fine with windows credential it is automatically login to Yammer.

Now to track whether user logged to Yammer or not I am using yam.platform.getLoginStatus.

So here I want to check user login status just after yammer embed sso done its job. So do we have any event to track whether automatically SSO done and user logged in so that I can do other operation based on it?

Or do we have any other way from **API to combine Yammer SSO checks**.

Also SSO is only available as configuration for Embed control only. Can we use with other controls “Like” and “Follow” controls?